# NSScroller draws above NSView

Tags: macos, drawing, nsview, nsscrollview, nsscroller

I have NSView with 2 subviews: NSScrollView(with NSTableView inside) and custom NSView. Sometimes i need to resize custom NSView to show it above part of NSScrollView, but when i'm scrolling content of table NSScroller draws above my custom NSView. How to avoid it?

Comment: When you resize your custom view larger, are you also resizing your scroll view smaller -- I think you would have to to make this work.  Better yet, embed both views in a split view.

Comment: You can remove and add the custom view again before resize. So the custom view will come as front most view.